# How to install splinter on python3 on win10

Tags: splinter

I'm new to python and I've found that some people have used python 3.6 and splinter to complete some projects[click here to see](https://www.2cto.com/kf/201801/714445.html), but I found that some people said that it's not compatible to python 3...and some people said that some special operations can get it installed.
I am confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following command:-

```
C:\ python -m pip install splinter
```

or

```
C:\ pip install splinter
```